# Why does my content go under my footer?

Tags: css

I'm sort of a noob to developing websites, but hope to learn more. The problem I'm having is that my main page content goes under my footer if the page holds more and more content. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/txAXM.png )

Either I'm doing something wrong, or I'm just missing something but, here's how I did it:

How could I fix this? Do I have to add/remove something?
The "position: absolute" is so it says at the bottom

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0 0 65px;
background: #000000 url(../images/bg.png);
padding-bottom: 65px;
}

#menu {
height: 50px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
background: #ccc no-repeat left top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
float: left;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 18px;
margin-right: 1px;
background: lightgray no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: darkgray;
}

.main {
width: 1300px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
border: 1px black solid;
}

.content {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 800px;
float: left;
background: white;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.content h2 {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px solid #696969;
width: 300px;
float: right;
background: #EDEDED;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.sidebar h2 {
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
text-align: center;
}


#footer {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #ccc no-repeat left;
border-top: 3px solid;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 65px;
width: 100%;
}

#footer .footer-content {
font-weight: bold;
color: #262626;
font-size: 14;
}

#footer .footer-content a {
color: #545454;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
}

#footer .footer-content a:hover {
color: #6E6E6E;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-content">
        <center>
            <a href="">Home</a> | <a href="">Forums</a> | <a href="">Contact</a> | <a href="">Signup</a> |<a href="">Login</a>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Fixed

I seemed to have fixed my problem. I just added:

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Well... you have given the `footer` a `position: absolute`, so it sits on top of the content. Why did you do that? If you remove it it should be fine.

Comment: your footer is absolute positioned and depending on the css of the main content and body you are putting the footer at the bottom right of screen.

Comment: You should show more css to get a fully accurate answer

Comment: Can you set this up in a jsfiddle with a link?

Comment: Adding a non breaking space doesnt solve it here http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/9k7a50er/4/

Comment: You want position fixed

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're footer has `position: absolute;` applied, this means it jumps out of the normal flow of the page. To fix it, add a padding equal to the height of the footer to the bottom of the page.

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 65px; 
}
```